# Дергается окно при изменении размера

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть приложение написанное на WPF. В нем есть небольшая странность: при изменении размера с помощью захвата мышкой левого или верхнего края окна, данное окно имеет дерганную анимацию изменения размера. При таком же изменении с захватом правого и нижнего края, анимация изменения размера плавная. Думаю, что это завязано на одновременное изменение размера окна и координаты верхнего левого угла окна относительно рабочего стола.

Можно ли как-то глобально отслеживать, что идет изменение размера окна и запускать перерисовку компонентов после ее окончания?

Еще одно решение, которое приходит на ум - запретить изменение размера окна с левого и верхнего края окна. Это возможно?

Comment: `DragMove` в вашем коде реализован, или нативно? Окно стандартное или кастомное? Как по мне, так это настолько редкий случай ресайза, что им можно пренебречь.

Comment: @aepot, окно кастомное. DragMove реализован в моем коде. Ради эксперимента использовал стандартное окно (Закомментировал свой класс кастомного окна и добавил пустой класс с таким же именем (чтобы не править xaml)). Окно ведет себя точно так же. Видимо из-за того, что контент размещен таким образом, чтобы максимально доступное место использовать. Я успешно этим случаем пренебрегал года два или больше, но сейчас у нас появился молодой и активный тестировщик. Вот и решил поискать информацию по теме.

Comment: Ну значит скорее всего тормозит ваш код, а не окно. В любом случае, надо смотреть в код, без кода и разметки не понять. Создайте воспроизводимый пример в пустом проекте, опубликуйте здесь код и разметку, в дополнение прилинкуйте гитхаб если есть.

Comment: Сейчас потаскал за левый угол размер окна в нескольких своих проектах. Проблемы не наблюдаю.

Comment: @aepot, может быть. У меня есть завязка на изменение размера,  которая приводит к отрисовке UI. Вот и интересно, если возможность управлять когда будет происходить такая отрисовка.

Comment: Возможность есть, но пока речь идет об абстрактном окне в вакууме, сложно понять, что именно нужн сделать. Может и не окно виновато, а контролы в нем.